# React Native ошибка при нахождении ключа

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile-development

```
ReferenceError: key is not defined
Main.deleteNote
C:/ReactNative/First/NewTodo/components/Main.js:70
  67 |  }
  68 | 
  69 |  deleteNote(){
> 70 |      this.state.noteArray.splice(key, 1);
  71 |      this.setState({noteArray: this.state.noteArray});
  72 |  }
  73 | }
View compiled
deleteMethod
C:/ReactNative/First/NewTodo/components/Main.js:20
  17 | 
  18 |  let notes = this.state.noteArray.map((val, key) => {
  19 |      return <Note key={key} keyval={key} val={val}
> 20 |              deleteMethod={ () => this.deleteNote(key)} />
     | ^  21 |  });
  22 | 
  23 |  return (
```

**Код**

Main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';
import Note from './Note';

export default class Main extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    
      this.state = {
        noteArray:[],
        noteText:"",
      };
    }

    render(){

        let notes = this.state.noteArray.map((val, key) => {
            return <Note key={key} keyval={key} val={val}
                    deleteMethod={ () => this.deleteNote(key)} />
        });

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.header}>
                    <Text style={styles.headerText}>Заметки</Text>
                </View>

                <ScrollView style={styles.scrollContainer}>
                    {notes}
                </ScrollView>

                <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.footer} behavior="padding">
                    <TextInput
                    onChangeText={(noteText) => this.setState({noteText})}
                    value={this.state.noteText}
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    placeholder='Введите заметку..'
                    placeholderTextColor='#fff'
                    underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                    >
                        
                    </TextInput>

                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.addButton} onPress={this.addNote.bind(this)}>
                        <Text style={styles.addButtonText}>+</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </KeyboardAvoidingView>


            </View>
        );
    }

    addNote(){
        if(this.state.noteText){
            let d = new Date();
            this.state.noteArray.push({
                'date':d.getFullYear() + ":" + d.getMonth() + ":" + d.getDate(),
                'note': this.state.noteText
            });

        this.setState({noteArray: this.state.noteArray});
        this.setState({noteText:''});
        }

    }

    deleteNote(){
        this.state.noteArray.splice(key, 1);
        this.setState({noteArray: this.state.noteArray});
    }
}
```

Note.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default class Note extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <View key={this.props.keyval} style={styles.note}>
                <Text style={styles.noteText}>{this.props.val.note}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.noteText}>{this.props.val.date}</Text>

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.deleteMethod}style={styles.noteDelete}>
                    <Text style={styles.noteDeleteText}>+</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>             
            </View>
         );
    }
}
```

Comment: Эта ошибка при рендере или когда вы пытаетесь удалить note?

Comment: Передавайте key как параметр deleteNote, т.е. `deleteNote(key)`, `deleteKey(id) { ...  splide(id, 1)... }`

Comment: спасибо, совсем не углядел за параметрами